# GNUPlot xrange using dates in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, gnuplot, xrange

I have a csv file "harvest.csv", one of the columns contains dates.
Here is what I came to (plot.rb):

```
require 'csv'
require 'gnuplot'

days = Array.new
mg = Array.new

csv = CSV.open("../data/harvest.csv", headers: :first_row, converters: :numeric)
csv.each do |row|
  days << row[1]
  mg << row[3]
end


dates = []
days.each {|n| dates << Date.strptime(n,"%Y-%m-%d")}

Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) do |plot|
    plot.timefmt "'%Y%m%d'"
    plot.title  "Best Harvest Day"
    plot.xlabel "Time"
    **plot.xrange "[('2013-04-01'):('2013-06-01')]"**
    plot.ylabel "Harvested"


    plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [dates,mg] ) do |ds|
      ds.with = "linespoints"
      ds.title = "Pollen harvested"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run plot.rb an error is raised:

```
 line 735: Can't plot with an empty x range!
```

Should I convert [dates] to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you're setting with `plot.timefmt` must match the one you're using in range. Right now the `-` are missing. Also, you need to set  `xdata` to `time`  to [set datatype on the x axis to time](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node290.html).

```
Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
  plot.timefmt "'%Y-%m-%d'"
  plot.title  "Best Harvest Day"
  plot.xlabel "Time"
  plot.xdata "time"
  plot.xrange '["2013-04-01":"2013-06-01"]'
  plot.ylabel "Harvested"

  plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new([dates, mg]) do |ds|
    ds.with = "linespoints"
    ds.title = "Pollen harvested"
    ds.using = "1:2"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't have enough reputation to up this answer(